# How to downgrade kotlin gradle plugin in android studio flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on Flutter project facing this problem after upgrading gradel to the latest version
is there any way to downgrade Kotlin Gradle plugin version or back to the previous version in android studio, please?

`* What went wrong: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher. The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':image_gallery_saver' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72`

I tried this solution but doesn't work

android/build.gradle

From

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'`

To

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'`

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

From

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip`

To

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the kotlin version in build.gradle(**root level build.gradle**)

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
```

**Note:** It's not recommended to downgrade the kotlin version for a plugin.

Comment: same problem when change from  ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20' to ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

Comment: You have to downgrade all your android-gradle plugin , gradle plugin and kotlin version.

Comment: or else locally upgrade the kotlin version of the plugin and use it .

Comment: do you know how to do it? downgrade all your Android-gradle plugin, gradle plugin, and kotlin version?

Comment: Why not you upgrade the plugin kotlin version locally and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my android studio version to the previous version and now the package is working fine.